# How do I add a class to a custom namespace?

Tags: vb.net, class, namespaces

I'm trying to add a class to a new namespace in my project. I have the following:

```
Namespace Admin
    Public Class Page
        ' Some Code
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I'm then trying to access that on my code behind file using:

```
Dim page As New Admin.Page()
```

For some reason, it isn't recognising **Admin** as a namespace, is there something obvious I'm missing here? I've attempted to add a reference to my namespace, but it does not appear in the list when I right click **references** and **add reference** in the solution explorer

Comment: VB appends NameSpaces you add.  So if the Project root NS is WindowsApplication1, that one becomes, `WindowsApplication1.Admin`

Comment: Where are these files?

Comment: @Plutonix: Yes, but the consuming file would also be in that namespace.

Comment: I was addressing why the OP may not see an Admin in any list.  But yes more info on the config would help

Comment: The class is in the following folder path: App_Code > Classes > Pages > Admin > Page.vb

The file I'm trying to reference this in is a codebehind in the root folder. My project namespace is Bard, and I'm trying Bard.Admin, but that isn't working.

Comment: My class isn't compiled to a dll, it's just an open file; is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how many people will need this, but it turns out the issue is to do with the "Build Action" setting on the class file in VS2012. I needed to change it to Compile, as opposed to "Content".

I'm unsure what this does, I just know that this allowed me to access the namespace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-vs-net-project-properties-and-wh and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552589/what-is-content-build-action-in-visual-studio for some more information.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is Simple, if you have specified the Root Namespace from the Project Properties > Applications, then you will need to call your namespace as

```
Dim page As New <Rootnamespace>.Admin.Page()
```