# how to add dependency files (images, databases) to visual basic (setup.exe) using (Microsoft visual studio Installer Project)

Tags: vb.net

visual basic 2022 .. windows 11 .. i have converted an old vb-2008 program to visual basic 2022 .. you can see the old vb-2008 program from my website (wa0h.com) .. i used (Microsoft visual studio Installer Project) to create a deployable (setup.exe) file for the new 2022 program .. when i use the new setup.exe file to install the new 2022 program on a different computer, the program does not work because the setup.exe file does not include dependencies such as (images, databases, textfiles, etc) .. when i run the new program in debug mode, the program works fine, so there are no programming
errors .. ? when creating the new setup.exe file, how do i include images, databases,
and text files in the setup file ? .. age 82 .. computer programmer since 1963 (60 years) .. an old timer

i tried everything i could find on the internet .. putting the dependencies in the main project folder, putting them in the primary output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552589/what-is-content-build-action-in-visual-studio