# I added a new XML file to my solution, but when I press F5 to test it I can't find the .xml file in the Debug folder

Tags: c#, xml

What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the file and open its properties (<kbd>F4</kbd>), then change its [`Build Action`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-vs-net-project-properties-and-wha) to "Content". This will cause it to be included whenever "Content" files are deployed. In this case, you may also want to consider enabling the `Copy to Output Directory` option (see below), which will copy the chosen files to the output folder. When copied, directory structure (if applicable) will be maintained, too.

[image]

Comment: That isn't working. :( Can this be because I'm using a Virtual machine with Windows XP (guest OS)? I haven't set any special configuration on ANYTHING so I would assume it would work as normal. :\

Comment: Did you `Rebuild Solution` after changing it?

Comment: You could also try toggling `Copy to Output Directory`...that one sounds very promising ;)

Comment: Make sure to switch "Copy to Output Directory" to "Always" or "Only when newer"