# More resource confusion

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, resources, buildaction

I have a project that has a bunch of images in the project tree.  One of the images has the `BuildAction` set to `Content`, but `Copy to Output Directory` is set to `None`.

What exactly happens to this resource?  Does it get compiled into the EXE? From what I understand about resources - nothing should happen to it; having this image in project is useless.  Correct?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.