# how do I get my image to appear or load at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm just doing a basic practice project that envolves a street light and the light/image changes color at the push of a button. at design time I can see all three of my images clearly but at runtime none of them will show up. I searched the hell out of google and I followed about three different examples but nothing will work.

this is what I have in my xaml code for the three images so far

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299" Margin="25,10,0,0"                     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227" Source="images/Stop.png" Name="imgStop"/>
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299" Margin="25,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227" Source="images/Caution.png" Name="imgCaution"/>
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299" Margin="25,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227" Source="images/Caution.png" Name="imgGo"/>
```

now here's my C# code

```
private void btnGreen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    Image myImage = new Image();
    myImage.Width = 227;
    BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
    myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"G:\Users\Jason\Documents\C# Projects\WPF\stopLightDemo\stopLightDemo\images\Go.png");
    myBitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 227;
    myBitmapImage.EndInit();
    myImage.Source = myBitmapImage;
    }

    private void btnYellow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnRed_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

what could I be possibly be doing wrong????

Thank You!!!

Comment: Is your xaml supposed to have the same image for `imgCaution` and `imgGo`?  Any error messages?

Comment: no for imgCaution I have an image with a yellow caution light, for imgGo is a green light and for red is a red stop light. In the design view I have them All stacked on top of each other, by the way i Got the images to appear at runtime when the app first loads but its showing all three at one time so you can only see the first image stacked on the top of all three.. this is what I changed my xaml to

Comment: <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299" Margin="25,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227" Source="pack://application:,,,/stopLightDemo;component/images/Stop.png" Name="imgStop"/>
 <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299" Margin="25,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227" Source="pack://application:,,,/stopLightDemo;component/images/Caution.png" Name="imgCaution"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299" Margin="25,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227" Source="pack://application:,,,/stopLightDemo;component/images/Go.png" Name="imgGo"/>

Answer (score 0):

If you have a picture of the source;

```
myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"/stopLightDemo;component/images/Go.png",UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: I changed my code reference to a pack format Ex. Source="pack://application:,,,/stopLightDemo;component/images/Stop.png" and in C# I have   myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/stopLightDemo;component/images/Stop.png",UriKind.Relative); image loads automatically but I cant get the event handler to work in where the press of the button switches to the corresponding image

Answer (score 0):

First, when your XAML uses a relative image URI like `images/Caution.png` you have to make sure that the appropriate image file is located in a folder named `images` in your Visual Studio project, and that its [Build Action](https://stackoverflow.com/q/145752/1136211) is set to `Resource`.

Second, in your `btnGreen_Click` handler you create a new Image control and set its Source property, but you never add it to any container control. Therefore it can't become visible.

Comment: would this be a situation in which I use data binding? if so do I do that in my xaml or in C#?

Comment: No, there's no data binding needed here.