# I want to embed a test file as part of a Ranorex test suite

Tags: ranorex

If I have a test file that I need to use to test an application with, can I embed that test file within a ranorex solution so that it deploys on the test system?

I am thinking of the way I can Embed files in a visual studio project something like this: [How do I add a custom text file to a visual studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591429/how-do-i-add-a-custom-text-file-to-a-visual-studio-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to do it is to add your file to your project, then set its property "copy to output folder" to "always".

Comment: That sounds more like what I want. I will try, thanks.

Comment: Haven't really used Ranorex for some time now but this is what I was missing and my solution is a bad description of this. I agree with Sup3rHugh - his solution is great.

Comment: In fact, the solution I gave also applies to Visual Studio. Ranorex solution is in fact a Visual Studio solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can. Just open a project, create a new folder to the folder structure and use the folder however you need. Remember to put it into the correct folder (the folder which is needed to run the rxproj test automations - eg. Bin)

Comment: Thanks, I will experiment with it and check back later.