# Add Image Folder to Resources

Tags: c#

I have thousand of picture that need to be embedded to my C# application. I make a folder inside the Resources, and copy all my file to this folder. I could retrieve my image, using relative path. But the problem is how I could make all this file included when I publish my application.

PS : I couldn't export all my images to resources, because my image folder contain a lot of sub folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select all of the images in Visual Studio, press F4, and change the `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`.

Comment: I couldn't select all the images because its on subfolder.

Comment: @l1th1um: If the images are not yet included in your project (i.e. that would explain why you can't select them all) then you need to include them by either including the entire folder or right clicking on the folder and `Add existing...` - you could even tick the `Show All Files` button on the `Solution Explorer`, select them all (they are a little grayed out) and then right click and select `Include`.

Comment: woow....thanks...you save my day :D. Just knowing that `Include in Project` thing :D

Comment: @l1th1um, fantastic! I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can set its `Build Action` to Resource (`WPF` only) or `Embedded Resource`,
however, sometimes a much simpler option is to deploy images with binaries.

See [this great explanation on build actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-vs-net-project-properties-and-wh)

Comment: I'm making winforms application. The main problem is, how can I import my image which inside many subfolder to resources