# Include files marked as "Copy to Output Directory" with Installshield LE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build, installshield, installshield-le

I'm building a Windows Service in VB.NET with **Visual Studio 2012**. I included **log4net** in my project to deal with logging information about the service execution. I created a `log4net.config` file, which I marked `Copy if newer` in its `Copy to Output Directory` property.

I added an Installshield LE Setup project to my solution, and selected `Myproject.Primary Output` in the files to include. I expected my `log4net.config` file to be included in the setup since it's marked to be copied in output, but when I actually install it, it is not included. I already did research and found that I can turn the `Build Action` to `Content` for  log4net.config and then also include `Myproject.Content Files` in my Setup Project. It turns out it works.

However, after reading [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/145769/165055), I noticed that Build Action->Content is used to get files as streams, which is not really what I wanted to achieve with it

I would like to know if there is an other way, a recommended way to include my log4net.config file from the build into my Installshield Setup project ?

Comment: It seems to me that what you found is the way to go, even though you don't actually use the "stream" stuff. Otherwise, as far as I know, you have to manually add the file to the setup project through "2 - specify application data / Files"

Answer (score 1):

How about adding loggly related configuration in App.config file like below.
I am using it for hosting WCF service within Window Service and it works fine for me.

```
   <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

      <log4net>
        <root>
          <level value="ALL" />
          <appender-ref ref="LogglyAppender" />
        </root>
        <appender name="LogglyAppender" type="log4net.loggly.LogglyAppender, log4net-loggly">
          <rootUrl value="https://logs-01.loggly.com/" />
          <inputKey value="abcdefgh" />
          <tag value="log4net" />
        </appender>
      </log4net>
```