# Empty Bundle using MS Bundling

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization, dotless

I am using asp.net mvc4 and the built in bundling and minification that is provided by MS using the System.Web.Optimization library (1.1.0) with a custom LessTransform using dotless.  The site is hosted in IIS 7.  My problem is that intermittently the bundle is empty on the website which causes the website to load all weird.

```
http://site/Content/surveycss?
```

What could cause this?

**UPDATE**

1. I read that if the less compiler encounters an error it could result in an empty bundle.  I've tested the less for errors and there are none.
2. I discovered that there maybe an issue with the way that the bundle was configured to use the Content directory, so I changed it from:

   ```
       bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap")
           .Include(...));
   ```

to:

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/cssbundles/bootstrap")
            .Include(...));
```

After redeploying the application, it appeared to resolve the issue.  However, it's happening again.  The setup is a load balancer that with 2 IIS servers.  Today, I logged onto server 1 and browsed the site via IIS and it's loading fine.

Logging onto server 2 and browsing the site via IIS gives the bundling issue.

**Update 2**

To test the thought that the resource might be in use.  I tried deleting the less files that were part of the bundle that caused the issue.  The less files were successfully deleted.  Upon restoring the .less files, the issue went away when browsing directly to the server.

**Update 3**

This issue just started cropping up on the dev server which is not load balanced with a bundle that is not using dotless

```
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/cssbundles/bootstrap")
        .Include("~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"));
```

This was caused because of a nuget package upgrade and a file no longer being in the location it was referenced.  I double checked all of the other bundles to make sure the files still existed where they were referenced and they do, so that's not the issue.

**Update 4**

Added logging to the dotless configuration and received this message:

```
06-12-2013 16:08:07.814,10.183.130.143,demo.app.com,/cssbundles/bundlecss?v=WN4weCPcGs3GJ_Hgsm2B7qNotYNgbrMS6xwEt8SWK6M1,user@email.com,"
directive block with unrecognised format on line 1:
   []: /beginning of file
  [1]: @v: WN4weCPcGs3GJ_Hgsm2B7qNotYNgbrMS6xwEt8SWK6M1;
       ^
  [2]: @import ""~/Content/variables.less"";",Error,""
```

Thoughts?

Comment: did you ever solve this? it is happening to me now, and I am not finding anything on the web.

Comment: I believe that it was an error in the dotless parser not being able to support something or other.  I ended up switching from dotLess to Bundles Transformer: http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exact scenario occurred (`v=[no value]`) because the `Build Action` value on the `.less` file was accidentally set to `None`. This happened because the file was added to the project in an unusual way and then renamed to `.less`. Since VS.NET didn't know originally the file type it set it's property for `Build Action` to `none`.

Make sure the `.less` file has its `Build Action` configuration set to `Compile`, thus allowing the actual file is included in the build. This is also why the problem will not occur locally as it will be present, but once deployed it will be missing.

Comment: I know this is super old, I was going through unanswered questions, to mark answers where applicable.  I checked the files and they were all marked as Content, some were marked as copy always and others as copy never.  Would the copy never cause this issue as opposed to copy always / compile?

Comment: Yes - check the following for reference on descriptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-visual-studio-project-properties

Comment: Marking as the answer because I no longer have access to the issue and I know that changing the build action has fixed similar issues in the past.