# Compile image in .exe vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a simple .exe application in vb.net. The application wont have an installation just pure run on .exe file .

Application has one form and two pictures. When i set the option on image to build action - compile

[image]

```
Unable to open module file 'C:\Users\t3cho\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Apps\Apps\Resources\power.png': System Error &H80041feb&
```

Is there any other way to make an .exe file with images without installation or additional folders.

Comment: it might be how you are accessing Resources.

Comment: You are trying to embed your picture as a resource, so try the Embedded Resource option for the file and open it using the built-in classes for resource reading.

Comment: [What are the various “Build action” settings in VS.NET project properties and what do they do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-vs-net-project-properties-and-wh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to include images (and other types of resources) into the application is to right-click the project, go to the "Resources"-Tab and add the image there. You can change its name to e.g. `MyEmbeddedImage` and access it like this

```
Dim img As Image = Properties.Resources.MyEmbeddedImage
```

or

```
Dim img As Image = My.Resources.MyEmbeddedImage
```

This automatically sets the `Build Action` to **None**.

Note: This approach is type-safe and you will get errors at compile time, if the image is missing.

See: [My.Resources Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wkcc526(v=vs.100).aspx) and [How to: Add or Remove Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bka19x4(v=vs.100).aspx)

---

If you still want to embed the image "manually", you must set the `Build Action` to **Embedded Resource** and access it as @Icemanind describes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's called embedded resources. Set your image's `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`. You can then get the image at runtime like so:

```
Try
    _assembly = [Assembly].GetExecutingAssembly()
    _imageStream =  _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNameSpace.MyImage.png")
    ' Do something with _imageStream
Catch ex As Exception
    ' Resource not found or something went wrong
End Try
```