# Replace a file with another (existing file inside Solution)

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I have added the file *pluginsInHead.txt* as the image shows..

[image]

My *HeaderAndPlugin.cs* has this code:

```
private void changeFile(FileInfo file)
{
    File.Replace("pluginsInHead", file.FullName);
}
```

When running.. It breaks with this message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\washington.guedes\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\FilesAppManager\FilesAppManager\bin\Debug\pluginsInHead.txt'.

And, it is right.. because I went to that directory and *..bin\Debug* doesn't have the file.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are expected pluginsInHead.txt to be in your bin\debug directory, you need to set its build action to "copy file"

1. Select pluginsInHead.txt from solution explorer
2. Press ALT+ENTER
3. Change "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always"

Answer (score 1):

Right-click that file name, then in its Properties `Copy to Output Directory` setting mark  `Copy Always`. You can also check this SO question:

[What are the various "Build action" settings in Visual Studio project properties and what do they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-visual-studio-project-properties)