# My ASP.NET Core app in design time, the Login and Register urls are fine but after deploy only Login url appear ok while the Register url is empty

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

My web site was deployed in Plesk/IIS using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition web deploy tool.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Account/Login">Entrar</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can this problem be a Visual Studio bug that can be solved with Visual Studio components update?

Comment: you'll need to post your server side code in order for someone to help

Comment: The solution to my problem can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361736/asp-net-publishing-website-doesnt-publish-resources-folder