# The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

The Azure error is:

> .Net Core: Application startup exception:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file
>   'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional.

So this is a bit vague. I can't seem to nail this down. I'm trying to deploy a .Net Core Web API project to Azure, and I'm getting this error:

> :(  Oops. 500 Internal Server Error 
>   An error occurred while starting the application.

I've deployed plain old .Net WebAPI's and they have worked. I've followed online tutorials and they have worked. But somehow my project is broke. Enabling stdoutLogEnabled on Web.config and looking at the Azure Streaming Logs gives me this:

```
2016-08-26T02:55:12  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
Application startup exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Quanta.API.Startup..ctor(IHostingEnvironment env) in D:\Source\Workspaces\Quanta\src\Quanta.API\Startup.cs:line 50
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.StartupLoader.LoadMethods(IServiceProvider services, Type startupType, String environmentName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.FactoryService.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.SingletonCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureStartup()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: D:\home\site\wwwroot
Now listening on: http://localhost:30261
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Ok, that seems simple. It can't find appsettings.json. Looking at my config ( startup.cs ) it seems very well defined. My Startup looks like this:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    private static string _applicationPath = string.Empty;
    private static string _contentRootPath = string.Empty;
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _applicationPath = env.WebRootPath;
        _contentRootPath = env.ContentRootPath;
        // Setup configuration sources.

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(_contentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // This reads the configuration keys from the secret store.
            // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
            builder.AddUserSecrets();
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
    private string GetXmlCommentsPath()
    {
        var app = PlatformServices.Default.Application;
        return System.IO.Path.Combine(app.ApplicationBasePath, "Quanta.API.xml");
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var pathToDoc = GetXmlCommentsPath();


        services.AddDbContext<QuantaContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"],
            b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Quanta.API")));

        //Swagger
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
        services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SingleApiVersion(new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "Project Quanta API",
                Description = "Quant.API",
                TermsOfService = "None"
            });
            options.IncludeXmlComments(pathToDoc);
            options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
        });

        // Repositories
        services.AddScoped<ICheckListRepository, CheckListRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ICheckListItemRepository, CheckListItemRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IClientRepository, ClientRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IDocumentRepository, DocumentRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IDocumentTypeRepository, DocumentTypeRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IProjectRepository, ProjectRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IProtocolRepository, ProtocolRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IReviewRecordRepository, ReviewRecordRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IReviewSetRepository, ReviewSetRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ISiteRepository, SiteRepository>();

        // Automapper Configuration
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();

        // Enable Cors
        services.AddCors();

        // Add MVC services to the services container.
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(opts =>
            {
                // Force Camel Case to JSON
                opts.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
        app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod());

        app.UseExceptionHandler(
          builder =>
          {
              builder.Run(
                async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

                    var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                });
          });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            // Uncomment the following line to add a route for porting Web API 2 controllers.
            //routes.MapWebApiRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
        });


        //Ensure DB is created, and latest migration applied. Then seed.
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices
          .GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
          .CreateScope())
        {
            QuantaContext dbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<QuantaContext>();
            dbContext.Database.Migrate();
            QuantaDbInitializer.Initialize(dbContext);
        }


        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUi();


    }
}
```

This works fine locally. But once we publish to Azure, this fails. I'm at a loss. I've created new .Net core project that deploy to Azure just find. But this one project, that I put all my time into to, seems to fail. I'm about ready to copy and paste code out of the project that fails to run and into a new project, but i'm really curious on what's breaking this.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
So my Program.cs was:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace Quanta.API
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit2:
Per Frans, I checked the publishOptions. It was:

```
"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "web.config"
]
```

I took a publishOptions from a working project and changed it to:

```
 "publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "Views",
    "Areas/**/Views",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config"
  ]
  },
```

It still gave a 500 error, but it didn't give a stack trace saying it coulding load appsettings.json. Now it was complaining about a connection to SQL. I noticed that my SQL connection string code is mentioned in a lot of RC1 blog posts. RC2 of .Net Core changed it. So I updated it to:

```
  "Data": {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=QuantaDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  },
```

And changed my startup to:

```cs
 services.AddDbContext<QuantaContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
        b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Quanta.API")));
```

Finally, it worked.

I must have followed an older RC1 example and not realized it.

Comment: In the error message there is `Content root path: D:\home\site\wwwroot`. Is it expected? Is `appsettings.json` in the folder?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check the publishOptions in project.json and make sure the "include" section has "appsettings.json" in it.
They changed the publish model in RTM to require you to specify everything you want copied from the compile directory to the web folder.

EDIT: See Jensdc answer below for how to do this with .csproj after project.json was killed.

Comment: I think you meant appsettings.json, and it was not part of the publishOptions. I copied a publishOptions from a working project:

Comment: Oops, yes :) that's what happens when I answer on my phone :)

Answer (score 114):

In My case, the file `appsettings.json` existed in the project folder, but it was set to `Do not copy`, I changed the setting to `Copy always` (see images below). And it worked for me.

It will automatically add the following XML to your `project.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

I have looked at other answers, `project.json` is dead as this [answer](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/project-json-replaced-by-csproj) says.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of setting "Build Action" to "Content"?  It seems to work if this is set to "None."

Comment: @JoePC actually in my answer I do not mention any thing about build action setting and I do not remember why my setting was set to content at that time I made the answer. There is a nice answer that cover this part, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-visual-studio-project-properties

Comment: This worked for me (I had to re-set it to Copy Always for it to be included); then I included the json files by declating the path like this: `APP_SETTINGS = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "appsettings.json"); builder.AddJsonFile(APP_SETTINGS, optional: false);`

Answer (score 99):

In later .net core versions a ***.csproj** file is used instead of the **project.json** file.

You can modify the file to get the desired result by adding:

```
   <ItemGroup>
      <Content Update="appsettings.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
   </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019, accessing the Properties pane of `appsettings.json` via the Solution Explorer generates **_Include_** rather than _Update_ in **.csproj**: 
`<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>`

Answer (score 58):

**Update:**

From @bunjeeb in comments. Use `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory` instead of `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` for `.NET 5 <=` with `<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>`.

**Original:**

For me the error was using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. This worked fine running locally but on a production server it failed when the program was started from `Powershell`. Replaced with `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` and everything worked.

Complete code:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

var configuration = builder.Build();
```

Comment: In .net5, if you set `<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>` you will get a warning from VS telling you that `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` is always null. Instead use `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory`

Comment: +100. Oh man, you saved my day. This finally worked for me.

Comment: This is also useful for HostedService when creating a Windows Service

Comment: I'm using .NET 7 and one day my Program.cs file could no longer see the appsettings.json file.  My Azure database logins were failing because of it.  This was working fine previously.  I spent all day troubleshooting and found this.  Adding the new line of ".AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");" for the builder fixed it.  Have no clue why it was working fine previously without that line though.

Comment: Now it can find my `appsettings.json` but not certain sections `"Section 'XYZ' not found in configuration."` so painful lol

Answer (score 36):

In your `project.json`

ensure you have inlcuded `appsettings.json` as a `copyToOutput`

```
"buildOptions": {
   "emitEntryPoint": true,
   "preserveCompilationContext": true,
   "copyToOutput": {
     "include": [ "appsettings.json" ]
   }
 },
```

Answer (score 14):

For me, what solved was setting to include the `appsettings.json` **via interface** on the output directory (Build directory), like so:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to add your .json file to publish options.
it's just that it is looking for the file at the wrong path.

set base path and then add json file and it will work.

```
 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("TestJson.json");

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

here, startup constructor is built with with HostingEnviornment and base path is set to the current root path.
and it will work!

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was changing the **Copy to Output Directory property** on `appsettings.json` to **Copy if newer**.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up here when publishing my Azure Function from Visual Studio 2019. I got this error when trying to publish my function to the portal with an appSettings.json file. It was copying the appSettings.json to the **output** directory but not the **publish** directory. I had to add the line below to the .csproj of the azure function project.

```
<CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
```

So my .csproj would look like the below:

```
<ItemGroup>
<None Update="host.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="appsettings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="local.settings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error while the app is being run from network share. It even was trying to locate `appsettings.json` file at user's desktop.

I ended up combining the path with executable location, like below:

```
configuration
  .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "appsettings.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
  .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, $"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false);
```

Comment: This is all great for DotNet 5 and below, but DotNet 6 has me stumped as there is no longer a startup.cs file.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that the appsettings.json file was hidden. How it ended up being hidden I have not idea but the .netcore ConfiguraitonFileProvider has a check for hidden files and does not load them if they are hidden.

Comment: so how did u fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for... Someone trying to debug on VS Code, but appsettings.json is not being picked up. I tried debugging the same solution in Visual Studio, and it worked.
Also, I was able to access environment variables. App version: Core 2.2.

I deleted the .vscode folder and debugged again and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem while using .net core 3 and this is what worked.

```
<None Update="appsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

hope this is good

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got this error because of JSON file syntax error (typo: deleted comma).

By default, property "Copy to Output Directory" of appsettings.json set to "Do not Copy" which I think is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was using `config.GetConnectionString();` to get the value instead of `config.GetValue()`. That's after I enabled CopyAlways in when clicking on appsettings.json Properties (right click).

Answer (score 0):

In **.NET 6.0** (dotnet core) try using:

`System.AppContext.BaseDirectory`

instead of

`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

IE:

```
 var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .SetBasePath(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory)
     .AddJsonFile
```

This is what resolved the issue for me in an ASP.NET MVC app.