# 500 error while deploying asp.net core web api to IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have a asp.net core web api project which I am trying to host in IIS 7.5.

As suggested by below article,

[The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157781/the-configuration-file-appsettings-json-was-not-found-and-is-not-optional)

Below is my "appsettings.json" file,

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
"SchedulerConnection":   "Server=ABC\\SQL2012;Database=SchedulerDb;persist security info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
 }
}
```

And in "startup.cs" I am getting connection string value like below,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<SchedulerContext>(options =>
                                                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SchedulerConnection"),
                                                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("WebTest.API")));
    }
```

The code running file in local IISExpress, but throw 500 Server Error while deploying to IIS 7.5.

**What is wrong here?** please suggest!!

Below is my "publishOptions",

```
"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config"
]
 },
```

Comment: Now I am able to get connection string, but after hosting it to IIS 7.5, I am getting 500 Internal Server Error, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new login "IIS APPPOOL[App Pool Name]" for SQL Server and later assign website/IIS application to "IIS APPPOOL[App Pool Name]" works for me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Point the server to *\bin\Release\PublishOutput .

Select ApplicationPool .Net Framework version as "No managed code."
and Process Model->Identity as LocalSystem.

Restart both.

If same 500 error comes up then try self hosting it.
Link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298458](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298458/is-it-possible-to-self-host-a-asp-net-core-application-without-iis-not-web-api)

You will know the errors in your application.

Then Publish again and re-host.