# How to get the path of a "SelfContained" and "PublishSingleFile" exe?

Tags: c#, .net-core, exe, .net-core-publishsinglefile

I have a directory which contains a self-contained "exe" and a config file. The exe has to read this config file. But the problem is that the exe can not get the right path of this config file.

Let me first talk about how I did it.

1. Create a NET5.0 project in VS2019

[image]

2. Add codes

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestFile {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string assemblyLocation = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
            Console.WriteLine($"assemblyLocation=\"{assemblyLocation}\"");
            string configFile = Path.Combine((new FileInfo(assemblyLocation)).DirectoryName, "test.conf");
            Console.WriteLine($"configFile=\"{configFile}\"");
            File.ReadAllText(configFile);
        }
    }
}
```

3. Publish this project to a "SelfContained" and "PublishSingleFile" exe

[image]

[image]

4. Add file "test.conf" in the directory where the exe locates

[image]

5. Run this exe

[image]

How can I get the right path of this config file?

Comment: Try to mark `test.conf` with *Build Action = Content* and *Copy to Output Directory = Always*

Comment: Other option would be to pass path to `test.conf` as command-line argument and extract it within `Main()`

Comment: Neither of these two options. Is there another way?

Comment: Could you please describe what does not work with the two options?

Comment: 1, The config file should be modified for different users. 2, Later i will add "Worker Service" in this project and then this exe will be used as a windows service.

Comment: Maybe try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58307558/how-can-i-get-my-net-core-3-single-file-app-to-find-the-appsettings-json-file

Comment: thanks, Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule) works well.

Comment: I'm glad this helps!  If it's okay for you, I'll post an answer so that we can close this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this question: [How can I get my .NET Core 3 single file app to find the appsettings.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58307558/how-can-i-get-my-net-core-3-single-file-app-to-find-the-appsettings-json-file)

## .NET Core 3.1

Self-contained .NET Core applications are automatically extracted into a temporary folder. So the path of the published executable is different from the path of the executed assembly.

That's way you have to use this: `Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule)`

## .NET 5 and onwards

With .NET 5, this became easier: now you can simply place `appsettings.json` beside the EXE. By adding `var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();` the file will be read and the config can be accessed.

For other files, you can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

Comment: Note that this no longer works on .NET 5 unless you use the IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract flag, which reverts behavior to .NET Core 3 style self contained

Comment: What if I have another type of file that I need to access in .Net 6? not the settings file? Can I find the path for it?

Comment: @pauloya I've updated my answer. [See also here](https://github.com/mu88/Project28/blob/main/src/Persistence/Impl/Storage.cs#L48) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

I had read the recommended way was `Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)`, however this returned null for me (.NET 6). I suspect it's because the code was within a DLL from another project. In either case, a more robust method seems to be `AppContext.BaseDirectory`. It's used by .NET to search for assembly dependencies, and will point to the base application directory. Pretty easy to remember and will give you the directory rather than a filename right away!

Comment: AppContext.BaseDirectory did work without any issue for me.