# Not able to read the Connection String present in appsettings.json file when running the .net core Console application from windows task scheduler

Tags: c#, .net-core, directory, console-application

I have a .net core console application that is reading the connection string from the appsettings.json file. It works fine when I run the application from visual studio. But when I run this console application from the task scheduler it is not able to read the connection string from the appsettings.json file.

**Exception**:

> Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: connectionString    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value,
>   String parameterName)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder
>   optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1
>   sqlServerOptionsAction)    at
>   GetValueFromDBCore.TestContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder
>   optionsBuilder) in
>   P:\Users\vivek.nuna\Redis\GetValueFromDBCore\GetValueFromDBCore\GetValueFromDBCoreContext.cs:line
>   25    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider() 
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSqlRaw[TEntity](DbSet`1
>   source, String sql, Object[] parameters)    at
>   GetValueFromDBCore.Program.SetFreshDataInCache() in
>   P:\Users\vivek.nuna\Redis\GetValueFromDBCore\GetValueFromDBCore\Program.cs:line
>   30    at GetValueFromDBCore.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   P:\Users\vivek.nuna\Redis\GetValueFromDBCore\GetValueFromDBCore\Program.cs:line
>   18

**DBCOnext class:**

```
class TestContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<EmployeeEntity> EmployeeEntity { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();


            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("db_core_ef_first"));
        }
    }
```

**CS Proj file:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="2.0.601" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Note** I have made the console application exe by publishing it and gave the exe path to the task scheduler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to solve the issue, I was using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` in code `.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` so its working fine when I run from VS. I replaced this by `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` and it's working fine now.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56409888/6527049

Comment: This answer saves me. I was building a console app with `HostBuilder` and hosting the app with performing the scheduled task in Task Scheduler. But unable to get the value from the appSettings.json file. By removing `.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` this solves my issue. Thanks a lot.