# 'The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\appsettings.json'.'

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-core, desktop-application, winui

I am trying to implement configuration files in my WinUI Desktop Application. I keep getting the following error.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\appsettings.json'.'
```

I've set the build action to content and thte copy to output directroty to Copy of newer. But nothing works.

[Appsettings properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVagq.png)

My App.xaml.cs code is.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

namespace ManagementSystem.Web
{
    public partial class App : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        using (IServiceScope scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            IServiceProvider services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            MainWindow MainWindow = services.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();

            MainWindow.Activate();
        }
    }

    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((_, config) =>
            {
                config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            })
            .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
            {
                services.AddOptions();
                services.ConfigureServices();
            });
}
```

I have no clue why this is happening. I have tried googling it but I couldn't find anything as to why this is happening.

Comment: Why does your app start in that strange directory?

Comment: Not sure this is my first winUI application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157781/the-configuration-file-appsettings-json-was-not-found-and-is-not-optional)

Answer (score 1):

After some searching I found a fix for my problem.

Calling the following line of code before adding the Json file to my pipeline fixed the issue.

```
config.SetBasePath(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path);
```

Comment: where is Package coming from?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the `optional` property to `true`:

```
 IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder() .AddJsonFile(Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"..\..\sampleProject\sample\appsettings.json")), optional: true);
```