# Custom dll supplied by client - set up in vs project and git

Tags: git, visual-studio

Have a vs solution which is shared among a number of developers via git repo.

We have a dll that is an sdk for a client that we need for this project.  Unfortunately no Nuget for this dll.

Dlls are setup to be ignored by git so I can't just put it in the bin folder as it would get dropped by source control.  Is there a good way store a copy of this dll somewhere in the project and always copy it on build/rebuild to the bin folder.

A lib folder or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The best way:
   Set up a NuGet Server and deploy this library as NuGet package
2. Workaround:
   Create a lib folder, copy your library in this folder and add it to your source control. 
   Optionally you can use a build action on this file to copy it to bin folder
   (e.g. **Content**). [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the- 
   various-build-action-settings-in-visual-studio-project-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-visual-studio-project-properties). But in 
   general it is copied automatically into bin folder.

Comment: Don't need the build action step.  If I reference the file directly in the lib folder it is auto copied to bin on build/rebuild.  Since you are the only person who answered, I'll mark your answer as the solution if you add this as an option as well

Comment: Its a lot more straightforward than I realsised