# Copy file to debug directory on preview

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I use the *"Start without Debugging"* button in Visual Studio, my app is copied to a **debug** directory and runs from there, which I discovered via `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

However, there is a text file in the root of the project that I also need to copy, regardless of the build options.  When I press *"Start without Debugging"*, this file is never copied, despite the properties set:

[image]

Can anyone please provide instructions on what options to include this file when starting without debugging?

Comment: For a simple text file you don't need any build action to be set. You may try with Build Action: "None"

Comment: Wow - I hoped it was easy but didn't think it would be *that* easy.  Thanks very much.  I since found some reference material when looking up the different Build Action options (http://stackoverflow.com/a/145769/792888)

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, I don't have the "AdditionalFiles" listed in my WinForms app Build Action, also tried with VS2015.  Though setting the Build Action to "Content" works for me, when doing the CTRL-F5.

[image]

Comment: Hi.  Yes, I can confirm that *Content* works, although *None* is probably better as @apr suggested based on the supporting reading material in my link.  Thanks.