# How can I use a text file as a local resource file in a ASP.NET WebApi Application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, projects-and-solutions

I have a small WebApi project, and from inside this project I want to load a resource JSON file with some information. Inside my project I created a folder called `Resources`, and inside this `Resources` folder I added a `data.json` file.

I want to know how can I use this `data.json` file inside of my project. I did [some reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-visual-studio-project-properties) and wasn't able to find a *BuildAction* that puts this resource file on the same directory as my binaries so I can use it.

I would like to do something like this:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"..\Resources\data.json");
```

However if I do this I get this exception:

> "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Resources\data.json'."

I understand very little about ASP.NET, but is there a way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the build action you would set, it's the 'copy to output directory' you want to set to either 'always' or 'when newer'. That will copy it to a resources folder under your bin folder. Then, to get the data out, you would use Url.Content("~/bin/resources/data.json") assuming you were in a controller. That should resolve properly.

If this data doesn't change, the other option would be to make it an Embedded Resource which would then incorporate it into the web site's dll.