# What's the difference between Content and None when "Always copy to output directory" is set?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

In csproj file, we can include a file using either `None` or `Content` element. From MSDN, it says that:

> None - The file is not included in the project output group and is not
>   compiled in the build process. An example is a text file that contains
>   documentation, such as a Readme file.
>
> Content - The file is not compiled, but is included in the Content
>   output group. For example, this setting is the default value for an
>   .htm or other kind of Web file.

But since either `None` or `Content` element can contains a `CopyToOutputDirectory` element, thus I wonder if I set this to be `Always`, wouldn't the behavior of `None` and `Content` be the same?

Comment: When building an msi/setup project you can include different file types in the build and specify different locations for them. Ie you can specify that the `Content` files be placed in a particular folder. Note this doesn't answer your question, but pointjng out that the file types can/are used by other tools as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not everything which is copied to your output directory, by setting `CopyToOutputDirectory`, is copied to the *Content Output Group*. Therefore, you may do this:

```
File1---CopyToOutputDirectory = Copy always, Content 
File2---CopyToOutputDirectory = Copy always, Content 
File3---CopyToOutputDirectory = Copy always, None
```

All three files will be copied to output directory but only `File1` and `File2` will be copied to *Content Output Group*.

Furthermore, `Content` allows you to retrieve a file (in same directory as the assembly) as a stream via `Application.GetContentStream(URI)`. For this method to work, it needs a `AssemblyAssociatedContentFile` custom attribute which Visual Studio graciously adds when you mark a file as `Content`.

`None` and `Content` are values for *How the file relates to the build and deployment process.* Therefore, your build (MS Build for example) and deployment may be very different than simply taking files from the output directory. You may have a *.bat* file that you do not really need in the output directory but you need it for deployment.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-visual-studio-project-properties) SO answer has more details about the different build actions.

Comment: Why adding the `File1` and `File2` into your answer? It seems like only one of them would suffice. Am I missing something here?

Comment: An obvious difference I found is when they get published: "None" items don't get included in publish folder, "Content" items do. it only happens in some project types. eg: .net framework WebAPI application, .net framework Console application). but, .net core WebAPI application is not the case.

Comment: @KevinXiong that is a good explanation that makes sense. Published items get in to "app" but None items only show up for Test. Perhaps that is what Content Output Group is.