# an item cannot be found at the specified path

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, iot, windows-iot-core-10

On C#, raspberry, windows IOT, 
The app stop on this line

```
StorageFile file = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("Signature.jpg", 
    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

I get this error :

> an item cannot be found at the specified path

But Signature.jpg is on this folder existing

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Check Signature.jpg `Build Action` https://stackoverflow.com/a/145769/194717

Comment: Which folder the file exists?

Comment: In this folder : StorageFolder storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"\\myserver\signatures");

Comment: Hi cretgil, can the same app running on desktop access the file successfully?

Comment: yes on desktop the app access the file but not from a raspberry.

Comment: @cretgil It seems an issue of Windows IoT Core. You can submit this via feedback hub.

Answer (score 0):

I can also reproduce this issue when access the shared file on a computer from Windows 10 IoT core.

The workaround for this issue is that you can setup a web server to share the file instead of using file sharing. For example, I setup the IIS on my computer and copy the signature.jpg to the root folder of IIS(C:\inetpub\wwwroot). Then we can use the code below download the file from IIS:

```
    async void DownloadImageAndDisplay()
    {
        Uri fileUri = new Uri("http://{AddressOfPC}/signature.jpg");
        IRandomAccessStreamReference thumbnail =
RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(fileUri);
       StorageFile imageFile=await StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync("signature.jpg", fileUri, thumbnail);

        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamOverStream stream = (Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamOverStream)await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
        image.Source = bitmapImage;
    }
```