# Trying to get the image file from visual studio getting an exception

Tags: c#, .net, image, file, .net-core

Hi all i have image that i am trying to access that is having path below,

```
C:\migration-apidata\API\API\DesignHub\Images\img-min.png
```

with the below code

```
string fileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "//Images//img-min.png";
ImagePart imagePart = footerPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);
using var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read); // getting exception here 
imagePart.FeedData(stream);
```

I am not sure where i am doing wrong while accessing the file path and i have set the image properties like as below image

[image]

Could anyone please let me know where I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of a thrown exception?

Comment: Print  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory and compare with C:\migration-apidata\API\API\DesignHub

Comment: When you debug this, what is the value of `fileName`? Have you checked that the file is going where you expect it?

Comment: Just change the build action in the properties from "None" to "Content".

Comment: Here you can find a lot of information about build actions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-visual-studio-project-properties

Comment: the path coming as like this `C:\migration-apidata\API\API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\//DesignHub//Images//img-min.png`  for this code `string fileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "//DesignHub//Images//img-min.png";`

Comment: @Flydog57 the filename coming as this one `C:\migration-apidata\API\API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\//DesignHub//Images//img-min.png`

Comment: @SerafimProzorov i changed "None" to "Content" for image properties

Comment: Do you see your problem, you have a slash versus backslash typo.  You typed `"//Images//img-min.png"` in your code, when you meant to type `"\\Images\\img-min.png"`.  Consider using `@"\Images\img-min.png"`; it's less error-prone.  Also consider using `System.IO.Path.Combine`, it understands trailing backslashes and other common issues